# How to heapify heapq based on multiple conditions of same attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, priority-queue, heapsort

Let us say I have a class called Calculator, with attributes name, chocolate, cost, total = chocolate*cost .
I want to insert objects of Calculator class in a heap based on the following factors:

1. priority is given to total
2. If total is same, then see if chocolate == cost
3. If still a tie, break the tie based on what was in the heap first.

My inputs:

- A 8   2
- B 16  1
- C 5   4
- D 4   4
- E 2   5

Then pop each item from the heap.

Expected output:
C, D, A, B, E.

The Code I have written:

```
class Calculator:
    def __init__(self, name=None, chocolate=0, cost=0):
        self.name = name
        self.chocolate = chocolate
        self.cost = cost
        self.total = (self.chocolate*self.cost)
        
    
    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.total < other.total:
            return True
        
        elif self.total == other.total:
            if self.chocolate == self.cost:
                return True
```

Output I am getting, before popping. (The order as in heapq):

```
E 2 5
D 4 4
C 5 4
B 16 1
A 8 2
```

Desired Output:

```
E 2 5
B 16 1
A 8 2
D 4 4
C 5 4
```

What am I doing wrong? How will I know what is in the heap already?
Please explain me. Thank you.

Comment: Your `chocolate == cost` sort criterion makes no sense - you're only looking at one of the two items being compared, and completely ignoring the other one.

Comment: @jasonharper, the thing is priority is given as such, 
first to the total. If total is equal, check if both attributes are same, here it doesn't make sense, perhaps in a class like rectangle, where height and width are attributes, you give priority to the squares (same height and width) if the area (say) is same.
And finally, if there is still a tie, the priority is for the one already in the heap.

Hope this explanation makes sense.

Thank you.

Comment: @Prashanthv Heaps are not fully ordered data structures, so items that are tied are not necessarily anywhere near each other until they bubble up to the top couple of levels. You can't infer order of entry based on location in the heap. If you want to guarantee  order of entry, you have to store it explicitly. You can add a new field to each item, keep a global counter that gets incremented each time there's a new item, and set the item's new field to the counter's value. Then use that as the final tie breaker when comparing items.

Comment: @pjs, oh I see, now I understand. Since there is a name field, I can use the name and see which item was inserted at first. Assuming that the input file has names in the order. Also, I tried to code with that logic in c++, overloading the < operator. I got the required answer. However, when I copy pasted the same < operator logic in the python's __lt__ function, the output was different. Not sure what happened there. And I'm not sure if I have to continue in this thread or ask a different question for why that happened. I'll try to learn first, then ask if I'm stuck. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Every time you create an item object, increment a counter in the item class and set the counter value as an attribute of the item.  Voila', you can now compare items order of creation (assuming creation corresponds to insertion in the priority queue). Update your comparator accordingly.